# How to add custom menu item "Create a Meeting/Task" on ical popupwindow menu

Tags: macos, cocoa, icalendar

[image: This is snapshot to understand add new menu item in popup window of iCal]

Requirements :
The user will be able to Right click on the calendar and have three new options presented to them: Schedule Meeting, Schedule Call and Schedule task

My requirement is not seems to develop individual application.
After adding new meeting,call or task, All the data should be post to server.
I don't able to understand from where to start to make plugin for iCal.